# How to fetch a row in which one field contains a certain word?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Let's imagine we have a table 'recipe' in PostgreSQL DB. This table contains a property called 'ingredients'. It must contain a number of strings but Postgres doesn't allow it as I understand, so I store only one string with lots of ingredients separated by a comma. The purpose is to create a search by ingredients. For example, I write 'carrot' in the search field and get a recipe in which one of the ingredients is carrot.

How to implement it using Spring? The most desired solution is to use Spring's built-in classes and methods if it has anything for this case. But actually any solution will do.

Example:

```
|  id  |  prop1  |  ingredients    |  prop_n  |
|  1   |  ...    |  carrot, onion  |  ...     |
|  2   |  ...    |  beef, onion    |  ...     |
```

Search: 'carrot'

Get: row with id = 1.

Comment: `It must contain a number of strings but Postgres doesn't allow it as I understand, so I store only one string with lots of ingredients separated by a comma` => [Normalization to 3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) or non-atomic data type like [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html)/JSON

Comment: Storing comma separated values is a really bad design choice.

Comment: You should have three tables: recipe, ingredient, and recipe_ingredient. recipe_ingredient would be a join table between the two other tables (i.e. a row [4, 18] in this table would mean that recipe 4 uses ingredient 18). This table would constitute the join table used to map a ManyToMany association between the Recipe entity and the Ingredient entity.